# Photoshop scripting: save JPEG with different canvas size than document

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script

I'm writing a Photoshop script (in javascript) to save a copy of the document as a JPEG and I would like to save it with a smaller canvas than the photoshop document, without changing the document I'm in.

My current PS document is 3600x3600 at 300dpi. I would like the script to save two JPEG's, one at 2000x2000 at 300dpi and one at 1000x1000 at 72dpi, while keeping the original document at 3600x3600 at 300dpi.

Is this possible? As I hunt thru docs and forums, it looks like doing so requires changing the app.document, doing the outputs, then reverting the app.document to the original.

Comment: Are you really writing it in javascript, or are you using Photoshop's ActionScript3, based on, and stuck as, the 1998 version of JS? Also, as a PS scripting question, remember that there is [a far better place](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem/ct-p/ct-photoshop?page=1&sort=latest_replies&tabid=all) to ask first.

Comment: It is possible no need for reversion: you can duplicate a document - shrink it, save & close it & then swap back to the original document